# Set notation or formula for distinct elements from multiple sets

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, notation

Let:
$$ A = \{a, b, c, d, e\} $$
$$ B = \{b, c, f, g, h\} $$
$$ C = \{a, c, h, i, j\} $$
$$ D = \{ c, d, j, k, l\} $$

I understand the symmetric difference:
$$A \Delta B = \{a, d, e, f, g, h\} $$
But $$A \Delta B \Delta C = \{c, d, e, f, g,h, i, j \} $$

What is the notation for the set of distinct elements from each of these sets? This notation should describe the set $$\{e,f,g,i,k,l\} $$
What's the universal notation for such if you had sets $A_i...A_n$?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a widespread symbol for this. There is $n$-ary symmetric difference $\triangle$, but it means different from what you want.

However, you are not prohibited to define the needed operation yourself:
$$
\dot\triangle\{A_i\} =\left\{a\in \bigcup A_i:\left|\{i:a\in A_i\}\right|=1\right\}$$